# Como configurar cada item do combobox do tkinter para ter um resultado diferente dos outros dependendo da escolha

Tags: python, tkinter

Bom, eu criei um combobox porém não sei como configurar um item individualmente.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.tix import IMAGETEXT
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
import shelve
from urllib.request import urlopen


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Aplicativo de Organização")
root.geometry('1600x900')
root.configure(background="ghost white")


label = tk.Label(root ,text ='Qual a sua série?', font=' Verdana 25', background="ghost 
white")
label.place(relx = 0.40,
              rely = 0.01,
              anchor ='nw',)

combo = ttk.Combobox(
values=["4 ano", "5 ano", "6 ano", "7 ano", '8 ano', '9 ano', '1 série', '2 serie', '3 
serie', 'Não selecionado'],

)

combo.current(9)

combo.place( anchor ='center', rely=.1, relx=.48, width=200, height=29)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: e qual a finalidade quando o item for selecionado no combobox?

Comment: mostrar label por exemplo

Comment: Quero que quando o usuário selecionar um item “1 série” por exemplo, apareça uma etiqueta abaixo do combobox, mas esta etiqueta só será mostrada se ele selecionar “1 série”.

Comment: me ajuda por favor